# Subprocess is not working after rpy command

Tags: python, r, subprocess, rpy2

I'm developing a package that has basically 2 functions: 1) function that works using R via rpy2; and 2) function that requires subproccess.run() to run a perl program.

Interestingly, if I first run (2), the (1) is successfully completed. However, if run (1) and then (2), the (2) doesn't work (and worse, did not return an error).

Do you guys have an idea what is happening?

UPDATE:
Finally, I got the error message after subprocess.run() function. Basically, system is looking for files in "c/Users/PATH_TO_FILE/", however, it should be 'C:/Users/PATH_TO_FILE/'. Is there any way to change that?